# ASP.Net MVC Reference to existing item not added to list on edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my application I have many models, but the one pertaining to my question is:

```
public class MarketSale
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime SaleDate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DiscountedItem> Discounts { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Item> ItemsSold { get; set; }
    public decimal SalesTotal { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, there is a list of DiscountedItem objects, which are created at the same time as the MarketSale object is created and do not exist in any other context in relation to any other object.  The list of objects of type Item are references to existing items already in the database and are just added as references when the MarketSale item is created.  I am able to create a MarketSale item and properly add DiscountedItem objects in the list and add references to Item objects that already exist without adding new entries into the tables.  However, when I edit the MarketSale object, I am able to add new DiscountedItem objects but am not able to add references to other items.  When I go to the details view after attempting to add another reference in the ItemsSold list, it shows only the items added when the MarketSale instance was initially created.  (Item is the parent class to the following classes: Earring, Headband, Hairclip, Hairpin)

Here is my controller Edit method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,SaleDate,SalesTotal,Discounts,ItemsSold"] MarketSale marketSale)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        List<Item> myItems = new List<Item>();
        for (int i=0; i < marketSale.ItemsSold.Count; i++)
        {
            List<Earring> earrings = db.Earrings.ToList();
            List<Hairclip> hairclips = db.Hairclips.ToList();
            List<Hairpin> hairpins = db.Hairpins.ToList();
            List<Headband> headbands = db.Headbands.ToList();
            Item item = null;
            item = earrings.Find(c => (c.InventoryNum == marketSale.ItemsSold[i].InventoryNum));
            if (item == null)
            {
                item = hairclips.Find(c => (c.InventoryNum == marketSale.ItemsSold[i].InventoryNum));
            }

            if (item == null)
            {
                item = hairpins.Find(c => (c.InventoryNum == marketSale.ItemsSold[i].InventoryNum));
            }

            if (item == null)
            {
                item = headbands.Find(c => (c.InventoryNum == marketSale.ItemsSold[i].InventoryNum));
            }

            marketSale.ItemsSold[i] = item;
            item = null;                    
        }

        List<DiscountedItem> myDiscounts = new List<DiscountedItem>();
        foreach(DiscountedItem disc in marketSale.Discounts)
        {
            List<DiscountedItem> discounts = db.DiscountedItems.ToList();
            DiscountedItem i = null;
            i = discounts.Find(c => (c.Id == disc.Id));
            if(i != null)
            {
                if (i.DiscountAmount != disc.DiscountAmount)
                {
                    i.DiscountAmount = disc.DiscountAmount;
                    db.Entry(i).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                myDiscounts.Add(i);
            }
            else
            {
                myDiscounts.Add(disc);
                db.DiscountedItems.Add(disc);
            }
        }

        marketSale.Discounts = myDiscounts;
        db.Entry(marketSale).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(marketSale);
}
```

If anybody has any idea why this isn't working properly or any suggestions as to how I could improve my code or any other mistakes I'm making, I'd be happy to hear them.  Thanks!

Comment: If you use Entity framework or Linq, you might want to tag your question with it, this definitly seems like an entity problem -> you'll get faster answers. If the .Find() function return null while you obviously know the data exist, maybe it's a context problem. Your existing data comes from another context and you need to link the new context with the existing one or more likely, create your new object within the existing context.

Comment: Would the MarketSale relationship to the Item class be a many-to-many relationship? Could that be causing problems?

Comment: Did you try FirstOrDefault() function instead of Find() ?

Comment: The Find() function found the Item object just fine, my code just wasn't setting up the relationship properly.  I made a lot of changes, so I'm not sure exactly what the issue was, but I think the root of it was that the relationship in the models was not set up correctly.  After I added some more code to my model setup it now works properly.